# Python Error "global name is not defined

Tags: python

My code:

```
def check_File_Type(self):        
    suffix={"docx","pptx","xlsx"}
    if [self.file_path.endswith(x) for x in suffix]:
        print(x)
```

what I wanna do is to return the file type if it is one of those in suffix. but I get the error "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined". seems like I can't use "x" since it's in the [statement]? then how can I print the x here?

thanks

Comment: What exactly is the `x` you want to print? Do you want to print the suffix the path ends with?

Comment: yes, sorry I didnt explain it well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` from the list comprehension is local to the comprehension; in Python 3, a list comprehension is executed in a new frame (like a function) and names in the expression are locals.

Use a generator expression with `next()` instead:

```
def check_File_Type(self):        
    suffix={"docx", "pptx", "xlsx"}
    x = next((x for x in suffix if self.file_path.endswith(x)), None)
    if x:
        print(x)
```

The `next(iterable, default)` form returns either the first element of the iterable, or the default. The generator expression returns any `x` that is a suffix of the file path.

An alternative approach would be to use [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
def check_File_Type(self):        
    extension = os.path.splitext(self.file_path)[-1].lstrip('.')
    if extension in {"docx", "pptx", "xlsx"}:
        print(extension)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't help. You're not binding `x`. Why not use a normal loop?

Comment: @user2357112: indeed, I forgot to bind `x`, fixed. And there is a much better way, not using any loops but simply use `os.path.splitext()`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters splittext() is perfect for me! thanks!